# Need help writing a Javascript to add values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help in writing JavaScript code for my form. I need to add the values in the text fields(credit cards, payday loans and unsecured personal loans) and if the total gets more than or equal to $10000, on submit it should take the user to page 1, else page 2. I just want to add the first three fields, it doesn't matter what the user inputs in the other fields. Here's my form:

```
<form action="/fsg?pageId=0bd004f9-aabc-486e-be09-bf2621555e3e&amp;variant=b" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="pageId" value="0bd004f9-aabc-486e-be09-bf2621555e3e"><input type="hidden" name="pageVariant" value="b">
<fieldset class="clearfix" style="width: 297px; height: -17px;">
<div class="lp-pom-form-field clearfix" id="container_What_state_do_you_live_in">
<label for="What_state_do_you_live_in" class="main lp-form-label" id="label_What_state_do_you_live_in">
   State? *</label><select id="What_state_do_you_live_in" name="What_state_do_you_live_in" class="text form_elem_What_state_do_you_live_in">
   <option value="">Select a State</option>
   <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
   <option value="California">California</option>
   <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
   <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
   <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
   <option value="New York">New York</option>
   <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
   <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
   <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
   <option value="I reside in another state.">I reside in another state.</option></select>
</div>
<div class="lp-pom-form-field clearfix" id="container_credit_cards">
<label for="credit_cards" class="main lp-form-label" id="label_credit_cards">Credit Cards</label><input type="text" id="credit_cards" name="credit_cards" class="text form_elem_credit_cards">
</div>
<div class="lp-pom-form-field clearfix" id="container_payday_loans">
<label for="payday_loans" class="main lp-form-label" id="label_payday_loans">Payday Loans</label><input type="text" id="payday_loans" name="payday_loans" class="text form_elem_payday_loans">
</div>
<div class="lp-pom-form-field clearfix" id="container_unsecured_personal_loans">
<label for="unsecured_personal_loans" class="main lp-form-label" id="label_unsecured_personal_loans">Unsecured Personal Loans</label><input type="text" id="unsecured_personal_loans" name="unsecured_personal_loans" class="text form_elem_unsecured_personal_loans">
</div>
<div class="lp-pom-form-field clearfix" id="container_student_loans">
<label for="student_loans" class="main lp-form-label" id="label_student_loans">Student Loans</label><input type="text" id="student_loans" name="student_loans" class="text form_elem_student_loans">
</div>
<div class="lp-pom-form-field clearfix" id="container_auto_loan">
<label for="auto_loan" class="main lp-form-label" id="label_auto_loan">Auto Loan</label><input type="text" id="auto_loan" name="auto_loan" class="text form_elem_auto_loan">
</div>
<div class="lp-pom-form-field clearfix" id="container_medical_bills">
<label for="medical_bills" class="main lp-form-label" id="label_medical_bills">Medical Bills</label><input type="text" id="medical_bills" name="medical_bills" class="text form_elem_medical_bills">
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: So what have you attempted so far? We're not here to do your job for you, not just bang out some code. You show what you've attempted, we'll (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: We at Stack overflow are here to help not give away free code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please start by reviewing [How To Ask A Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

```
var total = $('#Creditcards').val() + $('#Payday').val() + $('#Unsecured').val();
    $('.submit').click(function(){
    if(total<10000) 
      {window.href.location = "x"}
    else{
       window.href.location = "y";
    }
})
```